# Synchronisation block does not work correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to run the below code but can't get the correct output.

Expected Output
"welcome new programmer"

Actual output
"new welcome programmer"

```
class First {
    public synchronized void display(String msg) {
        System.out.print("["+msg);
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Second {
    String msg;
    First fobj;
    Second (First fp,String str) {
        fobj = fp;
        msg = str;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(fobj) {       //Synchronized block
            fobj.display(msg);
        }
    }
}

public class SyncroBlock {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        First fnew = new First();
        Second ss = new Second(fnew, "welcome");
        Second ss1 = new Second(fnew,"new");
        Second ss2 = new Second(fnew, "programmer");
    }
}
```

Where I did wrong here?
Can anyone correct me please?

Comment: You are not doing any multi-threading here, so the problem has nothing to do with `synchronized`. If you remove the `synchronized` keyword / wrapper it will print the same. - Or did you forget something in your code? There is no `start()` method in class `Second` so this will not even compile.

Comment: @Jesper, he is doing, just missed `extends Thread` in the sample

Comment: In addition to the above comment: your `Second` constructor is calling the missing method `start();`. Did you remove important details by accident?

Comment: the start method is already defined in Second class https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper

Comment: note that the `synchronized` block is redundant because you make the `display()` method `synchronized`

Answer (score 2):

1. Starting a thread from a constructor is a bad idea. It violates the principles of safe construction.

   > A common mistake that can let the this reference escape during construction is *to start a thread from a constructor*. When an object creates a thread from its constructor, it almost always shares its this reference with the new thread, either explicitly (by passing it to the constructor) or implicitly (because the `Thread` or `Runnable` is an inner class of the owning object). The new thread might then be able to see the owning object *before it is fully constructed*.
   >
   > There’s nothing wrong with creating a thread in a constructor, but it is best not to start the thread immediately. Instead, expose a `start` or `initialize` method that starts the owned thread. Calling an overrideable instance method (one that is neither `private` nor `final`) from the constructor can also allow the `this` reference to escape.
   >
   > <sup>3.2.1 Safe construction practices, Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz</sup>
2. `Thread#start()` call might take some time, so the expected `"welcome -> "new" -> "programmer"` actually can be *in any order*.

To do what you were planning, we need to make sure that the previous `run()` has started executing before you go to the next one. For my machine, a sleep for `100L` between the calls was enough to get the right order.

```
Second ss = new Second(fnew, "welcome");
Thread.sleep(100L);
Second ss1 = new Second(fnew,"new");
Thread.sleep(100L);
Second ss2 = new Second(fnew, "programmer");
```

That isn't a good technique, you shouldn't utilise it like this. It makes execution sequential - we won't derive any benefits from multithreading.

Comment: @JaySuthar, you can accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to implement Callable or Runnable or whatever you need for your Second class.

Comment: that's wrong, neither `Callable` nor `Runnable` has the `start()` method